# Remove Spring Tool Suite Shortcuts from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Spring Tool Suite annoyingly overrides default Eclipse shortcuts. For instance, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, it opens Quick Search instead of showing Key Assist. This is annoying for other shortcuts keys as well.

How can I use the default shortcuts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the shortcuts are contributed by the various STS plugins there's no simple way to eliminate them in bulk. It's not even easy to identify them, since they don't use a common Category.
The best recommendation I can think of is to just eliminate them as you encounter them. That's what I did for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> when it annoyed me; I found it in the Preferences and remapped it to a different key combination, which brought back the default action (Key Assist). I think doing that on an as-needed basis would pretty quickly identify and eliminate most of the ones that get in your way.

Comment: The thing is that this is what I did and didn't work http://i.imgur.com/k5FFOQC.png

Comment: What is Show Quick Search mapped to in your workspace?